# how to apply numpy.where to a range of rows

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a 2d matrix file(`inputdata`) that contain `4` rows and `5` column as given below

```
1 2 3 4 5
0 2 2 4 6
1 2 5 6 1 
2 4 5 6 7
```

I want to make all values that are greater than 2 to 1 (only for second and third rows of second and third columns) using numpy.where

Expected output is

```
1 2 3 4 5
0 1 1 4 6
1 1 5 6 1 
2 4 5 6 7
```

My script is

```
import numpy as np
data=np.loadtxt("inputdata")
values=np.where(((data>2) & (data[1:3])))
data[values]=1
```

but the `second condition` (i.e. i want to apply the first condition of `numpy.where` to a range of rows only)

is not working.

I hope experts may help overcoming this problem.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.ix_` to take the subarray using advanced indexing, and then assign the results of `np.where` back to `x` with the same indexing:

```py
rows = (1, 2)
cols = (1, 2)
coords = np.ix_(rows, cols)
x[coords] = np.where(x[coords] == 2, 1, x[coords])
```

Demo:

```py
In [11]: coords = np.ix_((1,2), (1,2))

In [12]: x[coords]
Out[12]:
array([[2, 2],
       [2, 5]])

In [13]: x[coords] = np.where(x[coords] == 2, 1, x[coords])

In [14]: x
Out[14]:
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 1, 4, 6],
       [1, 1, 5, 6, 1],
       [2, 4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

For contiguous subarrays you can just use normal slicing (see AJH's answer). You can, however, still use `np.ix_`, which in my opinion is nicer to work with:

```py
rows = np.arange(1, 11)  # rows 1 through 10
cols = np.arange(4, 21)  # columns 4 through 20
target_value = 2  # The value to replace
substitution = 1  # The value used in replacement

coords = np.ix_(rows, cols)
x[coords] = np.where(x[coords] == target_value, substitution, x[coords])
```

Comment: I want to apply it to range of rows and columns how to do it using ur code, for simplicity i had mentioned second and third column

Comment: @mitu you can pass *any* row and column indices to `np.ix_`. For instance, if you want the second and fourth rows, and the first, third, and fifth columns: `x[np.ix_((1,3), (0,2,4))]`. The `np.ix_` function allows you to select non-contiguous subarrays as well as contiguous.

Comment: if i have 1000 columns and 1000 rows it's quite difficult to manually mentioned the column numbers, so if possible please suggest how to include range of rows and columns in your code. for example rows = (1:10)

Comment: Just use `np.arange()`, or normal slicing if you're working with contiguous subarrays... See my edit...

Answer (score 1):

Since the area you want to focus on is contiguous, you could make a subarray and then replace that part of the original array with the final subarray:

```
# Let's say your original array is called arr.
# subarray contains the 4 values that are in the 2nd and 3rd rows and columns.
subarray = arr[1:3, 1:3]

# Do your calculations on subarray and then change arr to match.
# This has the advantage of not iterating through all of arr, only the subarray.
subarray = np.where(subarray > 2, 1, subarray)
arr[1:3, 1:3] = subarray
```

Answer (score -2):

`np.where(a[1:3, 2:4] > 2, 1, a[1:3, 2:4])`

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?